# Can't build an .aab in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, build, android-app-bundle

When i'm running

```
flutter build appbundle
```

I'm getting the next error:

```
Gradle build failed to produce an .aab file. Its likely that this file was generated under /path_to_project/build, but the tool couldnt find it.
```

But i still can create an apk. And i can create an appbundle of a new-created projected.

So, what should i fix to get an opportunity to build .aab?
I can't just build a new project and switch code, because this is a 2-years project with some special lines in native code and idk where, because the previous developer added them, not me and i don't have an any connections with him :c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i had kinda outadated gradle version.
So i've changed it in

- myproject/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
- myproject/android/build.gradle

And thats all! Latest version i got from another flutter proj (i just ran `flutter create`
and looked into files of the new project).

Comment: I followed this path, and still get `Gradle build failed to produce an .aab file. It's likely that this file was generated under *redacted* but the tool couldn't find it.`

Answer (score 1):

Previously, I was releasing APKs and I switched the project to AAB. The issue was that I was setting my `archivesBaseName` in my *build.gradle* to contain more useful information:

```
defaultConfig {
    (..)
    setProperty("archivesBaseName", applicationId + "." + flutterVersionName + "." + flutterVersionCode)
}
```

This was really a bad idea when switching to AAB, because Gradle would search for a *app-release.aab*, thus I would end up with this error message.

The obvious solution is to remove that line, so the output filename is correct.